# What should I do if noexit is encountered in maze traversal algorithm pseudocode below?

Tags: c, maze

For maze traversal(put your hand to right...) , I have implemented below in C. It was working okey but it failed when all squares around are full. It stucks if it can not find a clear square to go. I have to backtrack it but I am struggling to find the solution. How to backtrack the way I passed before and find a suitable location to go?  (I can supply code upon request I have written but it is a bit lengthy)

pseudocode:

1. Take a step foreward.
2. Now, turn to your right.
3. Now turn left untill the area in front of you is clear.
4. Go back to 1.

Comment: Using that algorithm should backtrack already...? I would change 3 to 'while the area in front of you is not clear, turn to your left'.

Comment: When all surrounding squares are full, turning left continuously will not give any results. I have to remember where I walked down before and go to there and turn left and search exit. Do I have to log the square coordinates till that point always and revert back to there? This is going to be messy

Comment: There is a recursive way of this algorithm but I am trying to find a nonrecursive solution to this. Upper code fails when all suroundings are full.

Comment: @user1939432: Usually, backtracking (or undoing something) implies using a stack somehow to store the successive states. Does that help ?

Comment: If nonrecursive solution will be used, as you said some stack mechanism should be used. I do not know that chapter yet, probably I will delay this problem a bit further .

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between 'full because of a wall' or 'full because previously traversed'.